# GCD of two polynomials and expressing it as a linear combination

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Find the greatest common divisor $x^2-x-2$ and $x^3-7x-6$ in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and represent it as a linear combination of them.

I tried dividing $x^3-7x-6$ by $x^2-x-2$ and got $x+1$ with a remainder of $-4x-4$. I believe this remainder then becomes $x-4$ because we are working in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Then, dividing $x^2-x-2$ by $x-4$ gives $x+3$ with a remainder of $10$, which is $0$ mod $5$. Thus, I believe $x-4$ is the GCD of the original two polynomials because it is the last non-zero remainder we've encountered.

My question is whether or not what I have done so far is correct, and if so, how do I represent $x-4$ as a linear combination of $x^3-7x-6$ and $x^2-x-2$?

Thanks.

Comment: Given integers $a,b$, do you know how to find their gcd and write it as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$?  If you do, then the procedure for polynomials is exactly the same.  Your working so far is correct, though $x-4$ could be written more simply as $x+1$.

Comment: I have that $x+1$=$(x^3-7x-6)$-$(x+1)$$(x^2-x-2)$. But this is not a linear combination because the coefficient in front of $x^2-x-2$ is not an integer.

Comment: That's the answer, the coefficients don't have to be integers, they have to be polynomials.